# TAO exception: TAO (2723|139817071765312) - ServerRequest::tao_send_reply_exception, could not send exception reply

Tags: multithreading, publish-subscribe, tao

I have implemented a publish-subscribe server-pair using TAO's notification service in Linux. There are two servers E1 and E2. E2 has subscribed for news type, say 1, and E1 has subscribed for new type, say 2. E1 publishes news of type 1, following which E2 does some computation and publishes the result of news type 2, which E1 gets. This cycle goes on. The events are of CosNotification::StructuredEvent type. The problem is, the system gives lots of error messages after executing for some times at both of the server's terminal.

TAO (2723|139817071765312) - ServerRequest::tao_send_reply_exception, could not send exception reply

I am a beginner in TAO (as well as CORBA), so I am not sure whether this problem is because of threading or not.
If I use the following svc.conf at either of E1, E2 or both side, the event-communication becomes very slow:

static Server_Strategy_Factory "-ORBConcurrency thread-per-connection"
static Client_Strategy_Factory "-ORBWaitStrategy rw -ORBTransportMuxStrategy exclusive -ORBConnectStrategy blocked -ORBConnectionHandlerCleanup 1"
static Resource_Factory "-ORBFlushingStrategy blocking"

I copied the above options from TAO's website to have one thread per connection, thinking that the error may be caused by reaching thread limit.
Also I tried to have 
-ORBConcurrency thread-per-connection as command line option on both side of E1 and E2. That causes some CORBA-exception failing to start the servers.
Following are the commands I am using for running my system which gives the 
ServerRequest::tao_send_reply_exception, could not send exception reply
messages after sometime:

tao_cosnaming -ORBEndPoint iiop:localhost:12345 -ORBDaemon // to start name service
tao_cosnotification -ORBDebugLevel 10 -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaloc:iiop:localhost:12345/NameService -ORBDaemon // to start notification service
./E1 corbaloc:iiop:localhost:12345/NameService // starts E1
./E2 corbaloc:iiop:localhost:12345/NameService //starts E2

Can anyone suggest about what goes on here and how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some part has problems sending back the exception to the caller of a CORBA invocation. That could be any of the processes running. Try to run with "-ORBDebugLevel 10 -ORBVerboseLogging 2" added to the commandline, optionally you can use "-ORBLogFile foo.txt" to redirect logging to a file (use a separate filename for each process). That should tell you a lot more, which process has the problem sending back the reply and some more details about why.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What I could gist from the log files that E2 fails to parse some message, then E1 fails to read and then lots of broken pipe error in both the processes. Any suggestions on how to approach to those internal errors from my processes?

Comment: What TAO version and which OS are you running, see the PROBLEM-REPORT-FORM that is in the root of the package.

Comment: My system is Ubuntu 12.04. I had problem with installing TAO from source code, I installed from synaptic package manager and it shows version 6.0.1-3. Though in problem report form it shows TAO VERSION: 2.0.1 ACE VERSION: 6.0.1

Comment: That version is old, please upgrade to TAO 2.2.4 first which you can obtain from http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu